# Absolute Beginner: Can anyone tell me if this PCB is using AC or DC and if DC what component is converting the AC to DC on it?

Tags: pcb

[image]
[image]

This PCB is not broken. I am just trying to fundamentally understand how it works is all. I'm just very new to electronics.

This board is for a coffee mug heater with a cord for 110V outlet. This is the only piece of electronics for the device. The white connector goes to wires that heats up a plate. I've included the back as well. From reading everyone's responses and from reading [this article I searched up](https://resources.pcb.cadence.com/blog/2020-dc-vs-ac-current-design) thanks to the ideas in the responses, it seems that this PCB uses AC. I was previously under the mistaken impression that most PCBs use DC but it seems a lot of them use AC as well.

Follow up question:

If I wanted to test the voltage at a certain point on the circuit on the back, would I place the common probe on the ACN input and the voltage probe on the metal wire I want to test and put the setting on the appropriate type of voltage?

Comment: Is there any components on the back? The circuit can't be determined without showing all components and how they are wired.

Comment: And I say, as an Absolute Beginner you shouldn't go near it, if you even don't know if it uses AC or DC. Either type of voltage can seriously hurt you, even kill you.

Comment: The presence of the zener diode and the two large capacitors suggests that there's a low-voltage DC control circuit. But that doesn't leave enough components to implement the rest of the functionality, so there must be additional surface-mount components on the other side of the board.

Comment: CAUTION! ... every part of that circuit can be deadly when it is plugged in ... if the IC is a 3.3 V device, then it may be using 106.7 V for GND and 110 V for V+  (this is referenced to earth ground) ... the actual voltages can be higher

Comment: I have a question about your question -- as an "absolute beginner", do you even know what AC and DC are -- should we explain those first? (You're asking about them so I think not, but still, "absolute" is a strong word.) What does it matter that this question gets answered, what kind of an answer are you expecting from it? An explanation of the circuit, identify the components, just to satisfy curiosity, etc.? Because, the basic question ("does it use DC and from what component") is trivial (yes; D1, D2), and there must be something of substance here -- could you rephrase it, perhaps?

Comment: Do NOT begin on something you can plug into the wall.  It is dangerous.  As in you could kill yourself!  It is ac and DC without isolation.

Answer (score 4):

The supply terminals are clearly marked ACN and ACL which means Alternating Current Neutral and Live.

The 97A6 is a TRIAC which works as an electronic switch that can be used to turn the mains output on or off by a small signal from the control circuit.

> If I wanted to test the voltage at a certain point on the circuit on the back would I place the common probe on the ACN input and the voltage probe on the metal wire I want to test and put the setting on the appropriate type of voltage?

That is correct. If I was to do this I would,

- Tape the board down onto an insulating material so that it won't move during probing.
- Make sure that the socket used to test the device is on an RCD earth leakage protection device to protect you.
- Make sure that the power polarity is correct and that ACN is actually connected to neutral. (Voltmeter should read 0 V AC between ACN and earth, 110 V AC between ACL and earth.
- Connect the meter to the output and activate the cup sensor.

It's most likely that the TRIAC has failed.

Comment: Why assume it's broken, and I believe the capacitive touch button control circuit works on DC which can't be measued in AC. How to set up the meter, AC or DC, depends on what you want to measure on the board.

Comment: Good points. I made an assumption that the board was faulty and this may not be the case.

Comment: Thank you for all of the great comments. The board is not broken. I am just trying to fundamentally understand how it works is all. I'm just very new to electronics.

Answer (score 2):

The device is powered from the (AC) mains via a capacitive dropper (a cheap method, but one that does **not** lend itself to safe probing since every part of the circuit is tied to the mains). It's also tied to the mains through the non-isolated triac connections.

The power supply consists of CX1 (dropper) with two 470K resistors in series (because of required high voltage rating to withstand the ~325V mains peaks) across CX1 as a bleeder (to prevent a potential jolt from the mains pins when it's unplugged), the two 1N4007 rectifiers, electrolytic capacitor C1 and the 5.1V zener diode ZD1. There's also a MOV ZN1 and an RC filter with the ceramic capacitors C2, C4 and R6 to give around 5V to the IC U1. There's a series 22Ω flameproof resistor R1 to absorb surges if the product is plugged in near the AC mains peak, and a 2A fuse.

R3 is a gate resistor for the TO-92 triac Q1.

R4 and R5 are series resistors for the dual LED.

U1 will be either an ASIC or a small MCU. It gets around 5VDC (but, as as above, it's **not** isolated from the mains, so potentially **fatal** to come into contact with when powered) C3 is probably for power-on reset.

Aside from the connectors and spring, that's all the parts and their respective functions.

Answer (score 1):

This board is mixed AC and DC.  Power control looks like a triac so operating in the AC domain.  On the other hand, there are two diodes on the back, a polarized electrolytic cap and a Zener, suggesting DC for the control circuit.